# java NullPointerException when parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception

I keep receiving a java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to store the  values into my Vector. Here is the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<autocomplete>
  <autocomplete_item>
    <title short="Forrest Gump"></title>
  </autocomplete_item>
  <autocomplete_item>
    <title short="Forrest Landis"></title>
  </autocomplete_item>
  <autocomplete_item>
    <title short="Finding Forrester"></title>
  </autocomplete_item>
  <autocomplete_item>
    <title short="Menotti: The Medium: Maureen Forrester"></title>
  </autocomplete_item>
</autocomplete>
```

And here is my updated code:

```
import java.util.Vector;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SearchParse extends DefaultHandler {

    Vector titles;

    public SearchParse() {
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        int length = attributes.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String value = attributes.getValue(i);
            titles.addElement(value);
        }
    }

    public Vector getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

}
```

The NullPointerException is occuring at the following line:

```
titles.addElement(value);
```

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually put the full stack trace from the NullPointerException in your question.  Otherwise, it is very difficult to debug.

Comment: as @Jason says, full stack trace will help identify which line its failing on. Also provide more info on what you've tried so far, what happens when you debug through it?

Comment: And point out the line in your code which caused the NPE (as told by the 1st line of the stacktrace).

Comment: Are you getting any output from the ` e.printStackTrace();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you did not initialize the titles Vector before using it.

you need to add the following in the SearchParse constructor:

titles = new Vector();

Answer (score 1):

We need the stack trace, but this kind of coding pattern is going to get you into trouble

```
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    try {
        docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    docBuilder.isValidating();
```

Do not catch any of these exceptions and then continue using the variable which can only be null. If you have no way to handle the exception, you must not catch them (or catch and rethrow them).

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I updated my code and made it a whole lot simpler. I also identified the line of the NullPointerException...